# Using a single quote in PDO statement gets automatically escaped

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm attempting to get an entry into a database with a single quote in the string. My problem is that it is going into the database with the escape included in the string.

when I run:

```
$var = "'12 Toyota 4Runner";

$sql=$pdo->prepare("UPDATE $tbl_name SET description=:var WHERE id=:id");
$sql->execute(array(':id' => $id, ':var' => $var));
```

In my database, the entry will be "\'12 Toyota 4Runner"

Is there a way to remove the '\'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

However, PDO has nothing to do with this quote - some other code is adding it.

Either [get rid of magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)
And take out all the escaping functions from your code, especially from that "all protection function" loved by all the new users.

Comment: I've disabled magic quotes and am still getting the same results. I tried searching for more on the 'all protection function' and can't seem to find where this comes into play. Can you direct me to a place where I can read more about this?

Comment: Also, I was not having this issue in MySQL, it only started happening when I want to PDO.

Comment: Surely you are getting the same results - they are already stored in your database. Need to clean them. But do you have it for the newly inserted data?